# Session variable is null immediately..ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

ASp.Net core 2.1

I set a session variable in one controller:

```
 public ActionResult setsession()
    {

       HttpContext.Session.SetString("name","Fozzy");

      return Ok();
    }
```

I can see the value in session at this point when i pause the debugger after 
 setting the session variable. Then, i try to immediately retrieve the session variable in another controller via fetch, but its always null:

```
   public ActionResult getsession()
    {

        var fozzy =  HttpContext.Session.GetString("name");
        // fozzy is null
      return Ok(fozzy);
    }
```

I have set a session timeout to 20 minutes (i think)

```
    services.AddSession(options =>
        {

            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        });
```

This is my startup.cs:

```
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {

            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        });
        services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "values", action = "Get" });
        });
        //if (env.IsDevelopment())
        //{
        //    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        //    app.UseHsts();
        //}

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

My problem is not setting session variables. I went through that nightmare. If setting the variables was a problem, .Net Core throws an exception. I've gotten past all that.

How do I get my session to retain values in ASP.net Core 2.1? Thanks

Comment: Have you called `app.useSession()`?

Comment: yes. i can set session variables fine

Comment: Is the client blocking cookies?

Comment: no, this is my localhost. so there's no blocking whatsoever

Comment: Can you check whether you get a get a cookie in the browser when you set some session value? You can check that for example by looking at the request in the browser’s developer tools and checking if the response from the server includes a `Set-Cookie` header.

Comment: i dont see any cookies

Comment: Thats strange, your browser settings or an addon might prevent any 3rd party cookies. If u have a browser on ur PC that u never use, give it a quick test with this one, as it might have default settings and will allow any cookies

Comment: @BoundForGlory I see you have two `services.AddMvc()` and two `app.UseMvc`. Please make these  single call.

Answer (score 2):

As per [the documentation on session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-session-state), you will need to follow three steps to enable sessions in ASP.NET Core:

> To enable the session middleware, Startup must contain:
>
> - Any of the [`IDistributedCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.distributed.idistributedcache) memory caches. The `IDistributedCache` implementation is used as a backing store for session. For more information, see [Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2).
> - A call to [`AddSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.sessionservicecollectionextensions.addsession) in `ConfigureServices`.
> - A call to [`UseSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.sessionmiddlewareextensions#methods_) in `Configure`.

So in addition to `services.AddSession()` which sets up the general session services so that you can access it in general, you will also need to do `services.AddDistributedMemoryCache()` in order to have some place to *store* the data. And finally, inside `Configure` you will need to set up the session middleware using `app.UseSession()` to make sure that the session data is read when the request is being handled so that you can access the previously stored data.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, after setting "options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;" on AddSession. everything working fine.

```
 services.AddSession(options => {
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
```

Comment: It is because you need to be GDPR compliant as explained [here](https://andrewlock.net/session-state-gdpr-and-non-essential-cookies/)

Answer (score 0):

I realize there is already an answer to this, however I had the same issue wherein the value saved to the session was not persisted, but managed to solve my specific issue.

I have two machines on two domains, on the one domain the session value gets saved as expected, on the other it is saved, and can retrieve it while in the save method, but from another controller/method it returns null. Figured it might be security settings.

Turns out my problem was caused by the CookiePolicyOptions in ConfigureServices: I had CheckConsentNeeded set to true. After setting it to false it was working as expected.

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {                
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your controller include following reference

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

Comment: This seems to be feedback on another answer, is that correct? This doesn't answer the original question, which was "How do I get my session to retain values in ASP.net Core 2.1?"